# How to send data from .net core api to azure log analytics

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-log-analytics

I am trying to send data from my .net core API 2.1 version to Azure Log Analytics.

Below is my code:

```
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Security.Cryptography;
    using System.Text;

    namespace xyz.Common
    {
    public class AzureLogAnalytics
    {
    public String WorkspaceId { get; set; }
    public String SharedKey { get; set; }
    public String ApiVersion { get; set; }
    public String LogType { get; set; }
    public AzureLogAnalytics(String workspaceId, String sharedKey, String logType, String apiVersion = "2015-03-20")
    {
        this.WorkspaceId = workspaceId;
        this.SharedKey = sharedKey;
        this.LogType = logType;
        this.ApiVersion = apiVersion;
    }
    public void Post(string json)
    {
        string requestUriString = $"https://{WorkspaceId}.ods.opinsights.azure.com/api/logs?api-version={ApiVersion}";
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        string dateString = dateTime.ToString("r");
        string signature = GetSignature("POST", json.Length, "application/json", dateString, "/api/logs");
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUriString);
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Headers["Log-Type"] = LogType;
        request.Headers["x-ms-date"] = dateString;
        request.Headers["Authorization"] = signature;
        byte[] content = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
        using (Stream requestStreamAsync = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStreamAsync.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
        }
        using (HttpWebResponse responseAsync = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            if (responseAsync.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK && responseAsync.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
            {
                Stream responseStream = responseAsync.GetResponseStream();
                if (responseStream != null)
                {
                    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        throw new Exception(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private string GetSignature(string method, int contentLength, string contentType, string date, string resource)
    {
        string message = $"{method}\n{contentLength}\n{contentType}\nx-ms-date:{date}\n{resource}";
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
        using (HMACSHA256 encryptor = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(SharedKey)))
        {
            return $"SharedKey {WorkspaceId}:{Convert.ToBase64String(encryptor.ComputeHash(bytes))}";
        }
    }

}
}
```

In the above code while accessing the

```
URL "$"https://{WorkspaceId}.ods.opinsights.azure.com/api/logs?api-version={ApiVersion}";
```

I am getting this error:

[image]

And because of this, I am not able to get a response in line

using (HttpWebResponse responseAsync = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())

Comment: is there a reason you are not using Application Insights (maybe in LogAnalytics-workspace mode)? there you have the rich SDK available

Comment: I can give it a try for app insights, but now looking to go with Azure log analytics.

Comment: I think @silent means that you can create an Application Insights with Log-Analytics enabled. Then your log will go to both of them.

Comment: @AshishShelar, the data is sent ok, but just no response, right?

Comment: @AshishShelar read this regarding the integration of LA and AI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/create-workspace-resource

Comment: @IvanYang yes right, no response.

Comment: @AshishShelar, I opened fiddler when running the code, and in fiddler, only status code is returned in the response. So I think you could only get the status code from response, but not the content.

Comment: I have figured out the solution for this. Thanks for all your help and efforts.

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue with the authorization and API version.
I was using API Version 2015-03-20, I have changed it to 2016-04-01.
I have found out this link which works -
https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2018/february/send-data-to-azure-log-analytics-from-c-code/

Also, there are multiple links that I have gone through.

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-collector-api